# Google Play Get total install and uninstall count

Tags: android, google-play, uninstallation, google-play-console, google-play-core

I am having my app live from very long time on google play.
I was searching for the below details which i am not able to find and not understanding from the console.

1. The final count of unique total install and uninstall of my app till the date (No monthly break up or percentage).
2. The final count of unique user install the app and uninstall till the date (No monthly break up or percentage).

Comment: did you check App Statistics in play Console? You chose the period you want and you can export to CSV

Comment: Yes checked. But not getting exact count for all.

Answer (score 4):

in Google Play Console from `Dashboard` chose `lifetime` then you will find the total number, for more details click on `Explore ->`

[image]

Then in the `Statistics` Page Remove all selected Countries and leave `All countries / regions` tag.

Then Click  `EDIT` beside `All events, Per interval, Daily` and choose `Cumulative`

[image]

The first row will be the Total number of user installs.

[image]

Then you can click on `New user acquisitions` to choose different statistics.

for the things you asked for:

1. choose `Users` > `User loss` > `All users` to find Total uninstalls
2. choose `Devices` > `Install base` > `All devices` to find Total installs from devices

Comment: What about uninstall?

Comment: User loss is the unistalls

Comment: @Manoj Did you manage to get the numbers you want?